# Address of string literals and command lind arguments

Tags: c

Hey guys i am trying to print out addresses of string literals and the start and end of the command line arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Address of argc: %p\n", (void*)&argc); //Is this how u find the address of argc?
    //How to find out the start and end of command line arguments?
    printf("Start of argv: %p\n", (void*)argv); //Like this? I am not sure...

    char* strLiteral = "Hello world";
    //how to find the address of "Hello world"? (Address of string literal)
}
```

I did my research and ive heard answers like taking address of a string literal is not allowed... Is this true? What do they mean by that? String literals dont have an address? Please show me how to get the start and end addresses of command line arguments as well. 
Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: "i've heard answers like taking address of a string literal is not allowed" - *where* did you hear that? **Writing** to said-address locations is not allowed. Using those addresses in read-only fashion, otherwise it would be impossible to send them to pretty-much any function expecting a `const char *` (like `printf` primed with a `%s` specifier, for example). They would be worthless if you couldn't use their addresses.

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12601183/859385

Comment: Are you related to user6146524?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368780/are-we-able-to-print-out-the-address-for-string-literal

Comment: The variable `strLiteral` is initialized with the address of the string literal `"Hello world"`.

Comment: @user859385 That answer is wrong about taking the address of the string literal. See the question linked by Michael Burr.

Answer (score -1):

You can take the address of a string literal. Have a look at the following code, in particular the line before the return from main...

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const int argc, char *argv[]) {
  assert(argc > 1); 
  printf("argc    == %d   &argc    == %p\n",  argc, &argc);
  printf("argv[0] == %s   &argv[0] == %p\n",  argv[0], &argv[0]);
  printf("argv[1] == %s   &argv[1] == %p\n",  argv[1], &argv[1]);
  const char *test     = "You can take the address of this";
  printf("test == %s      &test == %p\n",  test, &test);
  printf("*address of string literal == %p\n",  &"address of string literal");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the looks of this, ure taking the address of the variable test. Not the string literal. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `argv[1]` is the address of the first character of the string.  That's likely what you want to print as the pointer value.  `&argv[1]` is the address into the array of argv - completely different.

Comment: `argv[argc]` is at best undefined.

Comment: If you don't pass any arguments it will be undefined, hence why I added `assert(argc > 1);`

Comment: @Harry `argv[1]` points to a string and at the first character of that string at the same time. `&"this is a string"` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @selbie I'll delete my comment. I was trying to point out that you iterate over argv using something like `for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {...}`.

Comment: @2501 I've added taking a reference to a string literal to the code.